# Laravel + Image Intervention : Force download of file that is not saved

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, intervention

I want to simply upload files , resize them and then force a download for every uploaded file. I do not want to save the files.

Resizing etc. works fine, however I cannot manage to force the download of the new file.

```
$content = $image->stream('jpg');

return response()->download($content, $name);
```

The shown snippet results in

> is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

Most probably because $content is not a path but the actual data.

Is there a way to enforce the download without saving it first?

Comment: is it not an option to temporarly save te file and delete it after download?

Comment: it is an option, but it's not really clean in my optinion - however, thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @Christophvh you are not forced to do it on Laravel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = "https://cdn.psychologytoday.com/sites/default/files/blogs/38/2008/12/2598-75772.jpg";
$name = 'happy.jpg';

$image = Image::make($url)->encode('jpg');
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='. $name,
];
return response()->stream(function() use ($image) {
    echo $image;
}, 200, $headers);
```

Here's what we're doing. We're using Intervention Image to encode that image into the correct file type format for us. Then we're setting the browser headers ourselves to tell the browser what type of file it is and that we want the browser to treat it as a downloadable attachment. Lastly, we return the response using Laravel's `stream()` method and use a closure. We tell the closure it has access to the encoded data of the image with `use ($image)` and then we simply echo that raw data onto the page. From there we tell the browser the HTTP code is 200 (OK), and then give it our headers to tell the browser what to do.

Your problem was that Laravel's handy `download()` method is expecting it to be a file on the file system. So we have to stream it and manually set the headers ourselves.

You will need to write some additional code to handle different file extensions for the `encode()` method Intervention uses as well as the `Content-Type` returned. You can find a list of all available mime types [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

I hope this helps.

***Edit:*** Later versions of Laravel introduced the `deleteFileAfterSend()` method on the response object. If you are okay with temporarily saving the file to the server you can do this:

```
return response()->download($path)->deleteFileAfterSend();
```